# "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>( response )

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Within my code I am receiving the error

> "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Please note that response is coming from a server API, sample of data attached.

I have split the code on purpose as I have a dedicated method that will output the dynamic object but for testing purposes I have avoiding that.

```
var response = NetworkHelper.GET( url );
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>( response );
```

The error is being thrown on the following line of code

```
if (result.UniqueIdentifier != null && result.UniqueIdentifier != 0)
```

Sample data

```js
{
    "UniqueIdentifier":8529685323871177582,
    "Id":{},
    "IsLAN":false,
    "Language":"English"
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to debug? What is the value of result and UniqueIdentifier in debugger?

Comment: Check if you get valid json from your api. Tested your code with hardcoded json and seems to work properly

Comment: well `result` is null ... prolly becuase `response` is empty ... nothing that can't be check with simple debugging

Comment: @EylM I debugged
@Wokuo the api is sending what I pasted as sample.
@Selvin `response` contains the sample text and `result` is an {object} according to the Watcher

Comment: Type result.UniqueIdentifier in the locals window. What value to you see?

Comment: @EylM result.UniqueIdentifier
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UniqueIdentifier' and no accessible extension method 'UniqueIdentifier' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Additionally here is a screenshot of the contents of result

https://gyazo.com/25d59afa68394b92d5f1c5e2baae82b4

Comment: Can you paste the raw json you are getting?

Comment: @EylM Contents of `response` in raw format
https://pastebin.com/EqqY1bLZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the JSON is escaped and your result variable is basically a string type.

You need to properly unecape it, and then deserialize it.

```
var token = JToken.Parse(response );
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(token.ToString());

if(result.UniqueIdentifier=!0)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Using this method I got a new exception

"Can not convert Object to String"

Comment: @ClaytonC This is a late answer but if anyone bumps into such an error make sure you convert your HTTP response object into a String using ReadAsStringAsync() method from System.Net.Http namespace